# OpenShift - started getting 404 suddenly yesteray

Tags: openshift

Yesterday i started to get a 404 error on my free account on openshift. I can log in via sftp and see the files in the /app-root/runtime/repo directory but when i navigate to the page i get a 404. Does anyone have any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: I am not sure why this got downvoted. Is this not the right forum for these questions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting the gear, recreating it and then just uploading all the files again. Not a huge deal but kinda of a pain in the butt however it is a free service so i'll put down my pitch fork and torch.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you observe this, SSH into the gear and inspect the logs at `~/app-root/logs` (or, for some cartridges, `~/CART-NAME/logs`).